# 4 GB of RAM installed but only 2.97 GB usable. What gives?

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where did the other .8 GB of RAM go?](https://superuser.com/questions/7964)

I just bought a used MacBook on [eBay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBay) that came installed with 4 GB of [RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory). The first thing I did was installing Windows 7 using [Boot Camp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Camp_%28software%29). Here's where it gets weird. When I finally booted it up in Windows 7, I checked the *Computer* properties, and it said that there were 4 GB of RAM, but only 2.97 GB is usable. Why is that? Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you have installed a 32-bit version of Windows. 32-bit versions can only access around 3 GB of RAM.  The exact amount depends on other hardware that is installed. If you want to be able to use more than this then you need to install a 64-bit OS.

Comment: I'm going to make the wild guess that BFree has a 1GB video card or two 512MB video cards.

Answer (score 5):

The long, detailed answer requires some reading. It's worthwhile
though, see: *[The 3 GB-not-4 GB RAM problem](https://web.archive.org/web/20070614044606/http://blogs.msdn.com/hiltonl/archive/2007/04/13/the-3gb-not-4gb-ram-problem.aspx)*.