# Why is all my extra RAM marked as “hardware reserved” in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is all my extra RAM marked as “hardware reserved” in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/56157/why-is-all-my-extra-ram-marked-as-hardware-reserved-in-windows-7)

I have a brand new motherboard with 16GB DDR3 RAM, a 6 core CPU, and Windows 7 64-bit says I've got 7.96 GB free, and 8192 MB reserved for hardware use.

I find that a little hard to understand, as my HD5950 video card has 2 GB of DDR5 memory, and I tried all the above remedies to find that even though my memory is on the QVL for 4 X 4 GB of RAM, and my CPU is also on the QVL, BOTH the BIOS and Windows 7 report 16GB, but NOT available to use.

How can a hardware resource tie up 8 GB of memory?

I know that Windows 7 64-bit Home Premium is limited to 16GB, but 8GB reserved?

When I had 8GB of memory, hardware reserved was only 2 GB. By logical extension then, more memory means more reserved memory for the hardware, which didn't change?

Microsoft says it is a hardware problem, my motherboard manufacturer says it's a problem with the OS.  One tech even suggested removing half my memory so I'll have more free percentage of memory available. I thought that since the hardware supported 32 GB of memory, and the OS supports only 16 GB of memory that I would reap the best benefits from the lesser memory configuration.

Comment: Might help: [Why is all my extra RAM marked as “hardware reserved” in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/56157) (same title as your question)

Comment: To help us answer your question, it should contain less small talk (to prevent TL;DR) and more specs (which motherboard, which CPU, which memory sticks).

Comment: It can't be an OS problem if the BIOS reports the memory unusable.