# Hardware reserved ram

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have 16 GB ram ,2 8 GB Memory Sticks.

my CPU is AMD FX 8350,ASUS M5A78LM USB3 motherboard and and corsair 1600Mhz 2 8gb ram sticks

i have using it for a while and it has been working great.

just today i start my PC and see hardware reserved memory as 8GB and and in properties it showed 16GB(7.98 usable).

so i called my brother and he removed memory stick and again inserted it and when i start computer it is again normal.

I just wanted to know what could have caused that problem ? and will i have to remove the memory stick each time this happens ? will the issue persist ?.

Comment: Welcome to this site. We would be able to better help you if some additional information was provided (which CPU, Motherboard and RAM models you have). Anyway, check answers to this (possible duplicate) question: [Why is all my extra RAM marked as “hardware reserved” in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/56157/why-is-all-my-extra-ram-marked-as-hardware-reserved-in-windows-7)

Comment: i checked that question,did not found my answer and i added the hardware config.

Comment: Please someone help me.This problem is still existing.But now when i restrart it again shows 16GB and after sometime the problem repeats itself.

Comment: Can you inform us the *exact* model of your memory sticks? For example: Mine is the `CMY8GX3M2A1866C9`. And please, what slots are they connected to in the motherboard? Also, can you make sure it's running at 1600 MHz? (You can use HWInfo for this). Let me know in the comments (use the `@` symbol before typing my name, like you would on Twitter). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem with one of the RAM sticks not being detected may or may not be persistent, based on whether or not there is an intermittent problem with a malfunctioning sector on one of the RAM sticks. Check the Windows System Information utility (*Start* menu -> *Run* -> type `msinfo32` -> press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) from time to time to see if all 16GB of your computer's RAM is detected. If one RAM stick keeps on going missing, this will give you some time to think about replacing it.

Comment: Thanks.The issue is solved already i forgot to update.I am sorry.One of the ram sticks was not good and i had it replaced.