# Windows 10 uses only 8GB RAM out of 12GB installed (and detected)

Tags: windows-10, memory

[image]

As you can see from the picture, not only the BIOS sees my 12GB, but Windows does too. It even shows it in the Task Manager, not just the CPU-Z.

Strangely though, it doesn't use them.

I have to note at that point that:

- **Ubuntu** does that too, even though **it detects the 12GB RAM** as well
- I've recently **installed SSD** and installed the fresh Dual Boot in them
- In the **old setup** (HDD) **the 12GB was completely usable** on both OSes.
- It says in the details that 4GB out of them are **Hardware Reserved**, so I have the questions:

  - Why did that not happen in the previous install?
  - Why doesn't Ubuntu use them as well then?
  - Why OS uses a big amount of RAM even though I have a few light programs running?

---

My question is not duplicate of [Why is all my extra RAM marked as “hardware reserved” in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/56157/why-is-all-my-extra-ram-marked-as-hardware-reserved-in-windows-7) in my opinion as my only mistake was that the RAM was a little bit out of place from the Motherboard. But it's a very similar case though and the Answer of the other question nicely puts that it's an interesting thing that the RAM was completely detected but nothing complained about its usability.

Comment: **Hardware Reserved: 4 GB**  If you have an Intel CPU, then you likely have configured your firmware, in such a way memory is being reserved for the iGPU.

Comment: I was gonna edit my answer, but then an Edit from you happened (thank you for the image). Refresh in 10 sec.

Comment: While installing the SSD you might have knocked or moved the RAM. Make sure it is well seated and secure.

Comment: @Mokubai you are correct. The Motherboard's RAM 1 Locker was unlocked. Don't know how that happened, but maybe I did it by mistake while installing the SSD. I thought like Ramhound that because the RAM was detected it couldn't be that case. But as it seems some of the Info pins of the RAM were nicely put.

Comment: The memory has an SPD chip that tells the system what size and specifications the RAM has. The memory controller then probably does some training and address and data line checks to make sure it's actually able to talk to it. Chances are in your case the SPD chip lines were connected, others were not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RAM is present but partly unusable.

This can happen if you have installed it in a socket configuration that is
unacceptable to the motherboard, or even if a RAM stick is defective.

I suggest that you study well your motherboard manual as regarding
RAM configurations.

Comment: Correct. The RAM's motherboard's locker was unlocked, probably my dabbling hands did it while installing the RAM. Although, it was weird because it was detected by the OSes and the BIOS but none complained about its usability though.