# 2.5 GB usable RAM out of 4GB both in Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows-10, memory, bios

I have a Lenovo laptop that came with a 4 GB ram installed in one of its two slots. It supports upto 8 GB distributed in the two slots. It worked fine. But one day I noticed that my laptop is getting very slow and checked the available RAM in the windows task manager where it should 2.57 GB usable out of 4 GB, 1.4. GB system reserved. I thought it was a windows problem and did research online but nothing solved my problem. Now I am on Linux but the same case here. Whether I use a 32bit system or a 64 bit one, whether I place the ram in other slot or place a new RAM there. The problem remains the same. When I use the existing RAM with another 4GB in the remaining slot, it shows 6GB instead of 8. I checked the same laptop of my friend and it works just fine. My BIOS settings, version everything is exactly same as my friend's Laptop. Can anyone tell me what is the problem here with my PC

Comment: Maybe RAM is reserved by integrated GPU? What's your laptop's model?

Comment: My laptop is a Lenovo E49 @gronostaj

Comment: [Why is all my extra RAM marked as “hardware reserved” in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/q/56157/241386)

Answer (score 0):

It is a common problem with 4 GB memory, check if your BIOS has Memory Remap Enabled.

It should be in Chipset Configuration under BIOS. It **MAY** be caused because of the motherboard holding memory for VRAM or other I/O devices.

When you have memory Remap enabled it allows usage to full potential and makes complete system memory visible.

For more on Memory Remap checkout this [link](https://www.compuram.de/blog/en/memory-remapping-what-is-it/)

Comment: memory remap option is not available for my device in the BIOS