# 32GB RAM reserved for hardware on Windows 10 pro (64bit)

Tags: windows-10, memory

I just put my new tower PC together, but windows can use only half of the RAM (32GB of 64GB):

- Motherboard: AB350-GAMING 3

[image: Mainboard info]

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7

[image: CPU Info]

- 4 RAM Slots with 16GB each

[image: RAM info]

- Windows 10 Pro (64bit) with properly activated & valid licence

This is what Windows shows me:

Task Manager:
[image: Task Manager]

Resource Monitor:
[image: Resource Monitor]

msconfig:
[image: msconfig]

I tried changing "max memory" to this (it is automatically filled in when i activate the checkbox, which seems correct for 64GB in MB):
[image: msconfig - max memory]

But when i press OK it changes to 256 (before closing). Also when using the up/down controls 256 is maximum. When re-opening the dialog the numer is set to 0 no matter what i left it at.

bcdedit:
[image: bcdedit]

I tried setting `maxmem` using `bcdedit`, but it did not accept it:
[image: bcdedit set maxmem]

BIOS:
I updated the BIOS from version F10 to F25 (latest):
[image: BIOS Version]

Supported RAM:

- Supprtorted RAM Windows 10 Pro 64bit: 2TB
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/memory-limits-for-windows-releases#physical-memory-limits-windows-10

Other actions:

- Windows update is up-to-date
- I updated all drivers using `Driver Easy`

Other "solutions" i found on the internet:

- Running `sfc` - did that - all ok
- Running another windows' system check & correct tool (forgot the name) - but also all ok
- Disable page-file - i tried it - didn't work. (I also know it is not advised for other reasons).
- Disable or enable (instructions were not clear) Memory Remapping in BIOS - didn't find any such option.
- Disable Shared Memory (shared with OnBoard Graphics Card) in BIOS - no such option. Also i am using an "external" graphics-card, not the onboard one.
- Changing RAM Slots (when using just 2 of them) - i use all 4 slots - seems pointless.
- Swapping RAM around in the slots - didn't try - seems pointless - i have 4 identical RAM sticks. Why should it make any difference?
- Adjusting RAM speed multiplier and/or voltage - didn't go into this. All is set to its defaults "auto" - 2400MHZ - found one note, that too high values (above 3000MHZ) can make problems with 4 slots being used. I don't think that's it either. My RAM is recognized, but not used.

I want to use the whole RAM:
So how to fix this?

Comment: Dupe of [64 bit - Why is all my extra RAM marked as "hardware reserved" in Windows 7? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/56157/why-is-all-my-extra-ram-marked-as-hardware-reserved-in-windows-7?rq=1)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is all my extra RAM marked as "hardware reserved" in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/56157/why-is-all-my-extra-ram-marked-as-hardware-reserved-in-windows-7)

Comment: I would try slowing the memory down or disabling XMP as [this page](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/ryzen_7/1700x) seems to suggest that the dual rank memory you have will actually need to run at a slower speed. Next try swapping slots, I've seen some motherboards able to detect memory in a slot by reading the SPD chip but because it wasn't quite sat properly it wasn't making contact and the memory failed some test and the channel got disabled. Any chance of showing the "Memory" tab in CPU-z?

Comment: The PC is dead right now - does not even go into BIOS anymore only the fans are running with black screen - once i fixed this, i will add CPU-Z Memory tab as requested. - i tried setting memory speed to 1200MHZ as shown in Speccy, but the lowest value the BIOS allows is 1333MHZ. Since i was puzzled by this i did not actually try this configuration. I then assumed that one channel runs at 2400MHZ but each RAM chip at 1200MHZ, which made sense to me. But i tried with and without XMP. No change.

Comment: I tried to find the mentioned information on "this page". Do you mean this? "4 DIMMs  DDR4-1866" - does this mean i have to go down to 1866MHZ for them to work?

Answer (score 1):

The end of the story was:

**One ram chip was broken.** After removing it the PC worked again.

I did not yet put in a new one.

Comment: Does Windows now display all your RAM is being used correctly? I am glad you worked it all out. Good "end the story" yes? And, was your RAM overclocked?

Comment: It was not overclocked.