# System has 16GB of physical RAM but only 8GB of physical is usable?

Tags: windows-10, memory, computer-building

This is what I see in system info:

[the resource monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4SUw.png) --im rendering a video right now, so the in use is higher than normal

[the advanced boot options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42ZRB.png)

> [image: Image.]

My system is running Windows 10, B450 Tomahawk Max motherboard, Ryzen 5 2600, GeForce RTX 2060 Super GPU and Corsair Vengeance RAM.

The RAM is in slots 2 and 4 as it was suggested in the motherboard manual. Switching to slots 1 and 3 did not fix the issue. The BIOS recognizes both sticks of memory and the RAM modules I have are from https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/Memory/VENGEANCE-LPX/p/CMK16GX4M2B3200C16

I have tried going through all the processes of trying to fix this, like going into msconfig, regedit and installing the latest BIOS. None of these have worked and I'm still left with the same issue as before. Does anybody know what might be causing this or how to fix it? (the same issue as before means that it still is showing up as 16gb installed, 8gb usable)

P.S.: I've opened the resource monitor and it said that 8267MB are Hardware Reserved. I’m pretty sure this is the cause of the problems but I haven’t found any solutions.

Comment: Likely duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/56157/why-is-all-my-extra-ram-marked-as-hardware-reserved-in-windows-7) question.

Comment: We don’t know anything about your issue, so “ I'm still left with the same issue as before”, doesn’t tell us much

Comment: How much memory does the BIOS see? Exactly which Corsair Vengeance memory modules do you have? Which memory slots are populated?

Comment: Have you verified memory isn’t being reserved within your firmware?  Can you provide a screenshot of your Advanced Boot options?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Ok I've answered all questions in the post.

Comment: @Ramhound Doesn’t look like a duplicate, as OP has built his own PC, whereas the other question was a PC from a manufacturer running Windows 7.

Comment: @Valay_17 - A computer is a computer.  In a case like this there isn’t a significant difference that would invalidate the answer to the duplicate candidate

Comment: @Ramhound What about the Windows 7 vs Windows 10?

Comment: @Valay_17 - Since this is likely a hardware problem or a configuration problem the operating system isn’t relevant other than making sure the author is using a 64-bit version of Windows 10 (which is indeed the case). I don’t feel like wasting my energy into having a conversation about this topic with you. So I won’t be replying to any additional commentary directed at me other than by the author.