# windows use only 2,5GB RAM

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Using 3+ GB RAM in Vista/Windows7(32-bit)?](https://superuser.com/questions/17827/using-3-gb-ram-in-vista-windows732-bit)
>   [4 GB of Ram installed but only 2.97GB usable. What gives?](https://superuser.com/questions/50138/4-gb-of-ram-installed-but-only-2-97gb-usable-what-gives)

hi,
i have laptop: eME730G with 4GB ram. I have Windows 7 (32bit) Enterprise and windows use only 2,5 GB ram, why? How fix it?

Full infomation about memory:

[image]

Comment: Dupes  [Using 3+ GB RAM in Vista/Windows7(32-bit)?](http://superuser.com/questions/17827/using-3-gb-ram-in-vista-windows732-bit) http://superuser.com/questions/50138/4-gb-of-ram-installed-but-only-2-97gb-usable-what-gives

Answer (score 10):

32 bit operating systems can't use the full 4GB or RAM on your machine.

To fix it, you need to use a 64 bit operating system.

To explain it further...

32 bits can only access 4GB of memory because 2 to the 32 power is 4 billion. So 2 to the 32 power is 4 GB.

Included in that accessing memory space is video memory and other hardware related stuff, which takes away from your 4GB of addressable RAM.

Comment: What he said...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps NVIDIA ION that uses 0.5 GB (of the 3 GB Win7 x86 can use)?