# Why does Resource Monitor in windows 7 show half my memory as "Hardware Reserved"?

Tags: windows, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where did the other .8 GB of RAM go?](https://superuser.com/questions/7964/where-did-the-other-8-gb-of-ram-go)
>   [Why does Windows only show about 3.5GB of my 4GB+ of RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/27086/why-does-windows-only-show-about-3-5gb-of-my-4gb-of-ram)

Does anyone know why in Windows 7 Resource Monitor shows that I have 8 GB of RAM installed on my computer, but I only have 3.2 GB available as 4.8 GB are in "Hardware Reserve". I researched this issue and tried going into msconfig and making sure that in the boot options the number of processors and max memory options were turned off. I also opened the computer up and reseated each of the memory sticks while clearing out any dust that was in there.

Some info on the system I am using:

```
OS: Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit Edition
CPU: AMD Phenom X4 9750
Memory: 4 X 2GB DDR2 memory
Motherboard: MS-7548 (Aspen)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using onboard graphics?

Comment: 64-bit Windows contain both 32 and 64 bit versions Resource Monitor. Are you run 64-bit version from System32 folder?

Comment: Never mind, I'm an idiot.... I accidentally installed the 32-bit version of Windows 7 and thought I had installed the 64-bit version. It makes perfect sense now why I am only seeing 3.2 GB of memory, I'm sure the onboard graphics card accounts for the majority of the .8 that I am not able to use.